# Early development stage

Tags: development-process, tools

This might be a silly question... from somebody looking to make his programming more structured/less chaotic.

I would like to develop an application (web and mobile) just for fun/for myself. Before starting writing any code I would like to describe (in words) what the application is going to do and how it is going to look from a user perspective.

How do you call this stage of development? Any other keywords that I could google? Are there any tools/recommended styles/... for this or should I just write it down in a few paragraphs?

Comment: Description = Requirements. Look/feel = Wireframe (basically drawings).

Comment: Sounds like [Functional Requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some common terms for this, but not every term means exactly the same in every organization. Here are some suggestions:

- "requirements analysis"
- "functional specification"
- "overall design"
- "writing user stories"

As a recommendation for writing lean specs, start with [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html).

Answer (score 1):

As you are in a very early stage and try to get an understanding of what application you want to build, you may call this the [***inception phase***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182173.aspx), hereby using [RUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Unified_Process) terminology.

At this phase you identify the application purpose, get a high level understanding of the requirements, define the boundaries of your application (i.e. high-level "scope"), and undertake other preparatory tasks.  Although you could already think of some design orientations and sketches, the real design and development work has not yet started and the details of the requirements are still to be elaborated further (preferably using an agile approach).

You could also opt for a discipline agnostic terminology such as that of the [PMBOK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Management_Body_of_Knowledge).  In this case you'd be in a *project initiation*, as you're writing down what seems to be a [*statement of work SOW)*](http://itmgr.org/project-management/sow-statement-of-work/the-sow-and-the-pmbok/)  (i.e. "a narrative description of products, services or results to be delivered by a project").

Personnally I'd opt for the *inception* :  I believe it more accurately describes the creative activity you're doing now. The SOW rather suggests an administrative work (e.g. if you'd collect the desires and requirements from a customer).